# How to set the date to the message in Google API

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I have a requirement like update the gmail message in certain case. So I am trying to accomplish it by deleting the existing message and create a new message. But I want the date of the old message to be maintained.

Lets say there was a message sent on 1st July. I am trying to update the message content on 3rd July. So on 3rd July I delete the existing message using the messageId and create a new message. But I need the message to be created with date 1st July.

Using the below code to create the message and send

```
private static MimeMessage createEmail(Activity activity, String userId, String fromAddress) throws MessagingException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(userId);
    InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(fromAddress);

    email.setFrom(fAddress);
    email.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, tAddress);

    String subject = GoogleUtil.getFormattedEmailSubject(activity);
    String text = GoogleUtil.getFormattedEmailText(activity);

    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setText(text);

    //TRYING TO SET THE DATE HERE IF AM RIGHT. 
    email.setSentDate(new Date(544543676346L));

    return email;
}

private static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email, List<String> labelIds) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    email.writeTo(bytes);
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setLabelIds(labelIds);
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);

    return message;
}

private static Message sendMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email, List<String> labelIds)
        throws MessagingException, IOException {

    Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email, labelIds);
    message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the email's internal message time used by Gmail when you [`send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) email. But you can do that when you [`insert`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) email to the inbox. Just set [`internalDateSource`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert#parameters) to `"dateHeader"`, to tell Gmail that it should base internal message time on the Date header in the email.

```java
public static void insertMessage(Gmail gmail, String userId, Message message) throws IOException {
  gmail.users().messages()
     .insert(userId, message)
     .setInternalDateSource("dateHeader")  // <--- The Gmail internal message time will be based on the Date header in the email, when valid.
     .execute();
}
```